# Permissions between creators and submitters

Tags: permissions

Is it possible to distinguish between user rights between users who submit this record and users who approve the record? For example, if I am an approver I can not create or submit a record for the approval process. Only members or creators could enter a record. In other words, I want to adjust the visibility of a new button when you want to create a record. Make it visible only for submitter or creator only.

Answer (score 0):

You should create 2 separate profiles and 2 separate page layouts for Creator and Approver. This way you can separate their responsibilities.

- Creator will have - Read, Create, Edit permission
- Approver will have - Read, Edit permission

Also, specify initial submitter in the Approval process wizard as 'Record Creator'